# Delete incoming/outcoming edges from Object

Tags: database, orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1

I have several classes:

- City (Vertex)
- Route (Vertex)
- has_route (Edge between City and Route).

When I deleted the "has_route" class from the Database, the City's records are still has empty values of deleted "has_route" class in "IN" and "OUT" fields.
This is very strange for me, cause I do not have the edge class in the database anymore, but I still can see it when I'm querying the data.
[Screenshot of empty link on the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGbo4.png)

What should I do to not seeing the deleted fields on my data?

Comment: What version are you using? Have you already use the "CHECK DATABASE" command?

Comment: @ldacrema I'm using 2.2.31 version. No, I didn't use this command. Will try